# How to find source code of Perl module using XSLoader?

Tags: perl

I would like to view the source code of [`I18N::Langinfo`](https://metacpan.org/pod/I18N::Langinfo). If I go to metacpan.org I can find the source at

https://metacpan.org/source/RJBS/perl-5.22.0/ext/I18N-Langinfo/Langinfo.pm

but it is just a wrapper that calls `XSLoader::load();`. If I type `perldoc -l I18N::Langinfo` I get `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/perl/5.20/I18N/Langinfo.pm` but this is just the same file as on metacpan.org, and there is no other files in that directory either.

Where is the source code located?

Comment: On metacpan, you can view all of the source files in a distribution by clicking "Browse": https://metacpan.org/source/RJBS/perl-5.22.0/ext/I18N-Langinfo

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot Thanks, I missed that!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the distribution: [`Langinfo.xs`](https://metacpan.org/source/RJBS/perl-5.22.0/ext/I18N-Langinfo/Langinfo.xs). No use installing the source!

I18N::Langinfo's `langinfo` simply exposes C function `nl_langinfo`.

Comment: I see, thanks :) good to know. So then there is no source on my local machine? Only on metacpan.org?

Comment: I don't know what's on your machine, but it's not installed along with `perl`. It's available in far more places than metacpan.org, including in the [Perl5 Master Repository](http://perl5.git.perl.org/perl.git).